# Python, Selenium & Pytest - What is the best way to leverage login function before other tests

Tags: python, selenium, class, authentication, pytest

I'm using python, selenium and pytest to learn pytest and run some tests, which would involve logging into an app.

The test_authentication function works. I'm struggling to figure out the best way to handle the authentication function (from a high level). Whats the best way to leverage my login function in test authentication so that I can call it or use it, before calling my other tests? For example, one complete test might be login, and another is create an create incident and save it. Another might be login and create a change record and save etc. I was thinking maybe id have another file (setup much like test_login), in each scenario where I have create_incident or create_change, where I call test_login.
Also, if login fails then how can I skip tests? Thanks

```
# conftest.py
import pytest
import time
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def webdriver(request):
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver

    yield driver
    driver.close()

# base_test.py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("webdriver")
class BaseTest:
    pass

# test_login.py
import pytest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from base_test import BaseTest


class TestLogin(BaseTest):
    def test_authentication(self):
        print("test login called")

        driver.get('https://url.com/')

        time.sleep(10)

        driver.switch_to.frame("gsft_main")
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        time.sleep(2)
        username = driver.find_element_by_id("user_name").send_keys("username")

        time.sleep(2)
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password").send_keys("pass")
        time.sleep(2)

        login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('sysverb_login')
        login_btn.click()

        time.sleep(20)
        driver.switch_to.default_content()

        # Search for the user header to verify successful login
        user_header = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                          '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/header/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button/div/span[1]')
        assert 'System Administrator' == user_header.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could throw the login code into its own method, and then call it from your test whenever you need to use it. Example taken from the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) framework (which I built):

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class SwagLabsLoginTests(BaseCase):
    def login_to_swag_labs(self):
        self.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        self.type("#user-name", "standard_user")
        self.type("#password", "secret_sauce")
        self.click('input[type="submit"]')

    def test_swag_labs_login(self):
        self.login_to_swag_labs()
        self.assert_element("#inventory_container")
        self.assert_element('.inventory_item:contains("Sauce Labs Backpack")')
```

The second method is the test method, which calls the login method above it. You'll notice that SeleniumBase already takes care of the driver management. And you won't need any random `sleep()` calls because smart-waiting is built-in.

(That file runs with `pytest`)